# pip install でpyHookをインストール出来ない。

Tags: python, pip

WindowsにAnacondaを入れてPython2.7.11の仮想環境を作成しました。pyHookをpipでインストールしようとしましたが下記エラーのためできません。

```
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyHook (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyHook
```

どうすればインストールできるのでしょうか。

環境は以下のとおりです。

```
Python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)
```

OSはWindows10 64bitです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pyHock
http://sourceforge.net/p/pyhook/wiki/PyHook_Tutorial/

> System Requirements 
>   Windows 2000 or later (low-level hooks are not supported in earlier versions of Windows) Python 2.4 or later Mark
>   Hammond's PyWin32 library (formerly known as win32all extensions)
>   pyHook 1.4 or later

と書かれているので入れれるかはわかりませんが、

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyHook (from
>   versions: ) No matching distribution found for pyHook

pipのこういうエラーはソースをダウンロードしてインストールすると導入できたりします。（当方はMacなので確認できません。）

なので、

1. http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyhook/files/latest/download　からソースをダウンロードし
2. cmdでソースの解凍したところまで移動して　例）cd /path/to/pyHock
3. python setup.py install　とかでインストールできませんか？

自信はあまりないですが試してみては如何ですか？